# Django remove certain parameter from GET

Tags: django, forms, django-templates, django-views

I am doing filter using GET method and I would like to be able to remove only specific filters, how do I do that?

Now I have a form with token fields so I get id's of countries and towns:

```html
    <form id="search" method="GET" action="{% url 'selection'%}">
        <div class="bg-grey text-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield1" name="country">
        </div>
        {% if filteredcountries %}
        <table class="table table-list">
         {% for c in filteredcountries %}
         <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-remove="{{c.id}}"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></td>
            <td>{{c.country_name`}}</td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
        </table>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="bg-grey text-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield2" name="town">
        </div>
        {% if filteredtowns %}
        <table class="table table-list">
         {% for t in filteredtowns %}
         <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-remove="{{t.id}}"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></td>
            <td>{{t.town_name}}</td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
         </table>
        {% endif %}
</form>
```

**views.py:**

```py
def hotel_view(request):
    countries = request.GET.get('country')
    if not countries:
        countries = []
    else:
        countries = countries.split(', ')
    
    towns = request.GET.get('town')
    if not towns:
        towns = []
    else:
        towns = towns.split(', ')
    
    results = Hotel.objects.filter(Q(town_id__in = towns) | Q(country_id__in = countries))
            
    context = {
        'filteredcountries': countries, 
        'filteredtowns': towns,
        'hotels': results
    }
   return render(request, 'myapp/hotels.html', context)
```

Now I want to click the button and remove the specific town or country from the GET and remain the others. Can you lead me to the solution?

example URL before button click:

`..myapp/hotels?country=**2**%2C+**4**&town=2`

url after button click with country id 2:

`..myapp/hotels?country=**4**&town=**2**`

or after button click with town id 2:

`..myapp/hotels?country=**2**%2C+**4**&town=`

Comment: `%2c` is a comma, so it basically says `country=2, 4`.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't really matter in my question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do that in the GET not in your view? If you really need to modify the url is javascript an option for you?

Comment: @Chris I don't mind doing it in view if the url changes then. And yes, javascript could be. I need to somehow change the url with get params after he removes one of the param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution around using javascript and JQuery. The basic approach is as follows:

1. Store the current `window.location.href` in a variable on loading of page. Why?
   Otherwise each manipulation of it would result in sending a new GET
   request which is probably undesirable
2. Manipulate the string stored
   in the mentioned variable depending on the button clicked.
3. Preventing the submit button from firing directly but using the
   manipulated string

Here the script part with some comments:

```
<script>
    var current_get = window.location.href // Store current url

    var handleget = function(part_chooser, id){
        // part_chooser = country or town, id = pk to remove
        var parts = current_get.split('?');

        if (parts.length < 2){  // No get params to manipulate
            return;
        }
        var get_part = parts[1];
        var get_parts =get_part.split('&');
        var i; // To keep order of new href if important
        var str_to_handle; // Part to manipulate
        for (i = 0; i < get_parts.length; i++){
            if (get_parts[i].startsWith(part_chooser)){
                str_to_handle = get_parts[i];
                break;
            }
        };

        // Do manipulation and store new url
        var get_arr = str_to_handle.split('=');
        if (get_arr.length > 0){
            params = get_arr[1].split('%2C+');
            var index = params.indexOf(id.toString());
            if (index >= 0){
                params.splice(index, 1);
                params = params.join('%2C+');
                get_parts[i] = part_chooser + '=' + params;
                current_get = parts[0]+'?'+get_parts.join('&');
                console.log(current_get);
            }

        };
    };

    $('button[type=submit]').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = current_get;
    })

    $('.country-btn').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('remove');
        handleget('country', id);
    });

</script>
```

Some remarks

1. I intentionally did not use long chains of JS to shorten the code as IMHO it is easier to read step by step
2. The string manipulation can probably be shortend by clever use of regular expressions.

Comment: That's it! I just had to switch $('button[type=submit]').... with $('.country-btn')...

Answer (score 0):

If your tokenfields contain all the possible ids as a comma seperated list on loading a javascript for deleting the specific id from the tokenfield could look like this:

```
<script>
    $('.country-btn').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('remove');
        var countries = $('#tokenfield1').val().split(',');
        var index = countries.indexOf(id.toString());
        if (index >= 0){
            countries.splice(index, 1)
        }
        $('#tokenfield1').val(countries.join());
    })

</script>
```

In order to fill your tokenfield with the ids returned in the context you could do something like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield1" name="country" 
       value="{% for c in filteredcountries %}{{c.id}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to run it through backend again to select related hotels to the filtering. So that is why I need to edit the GET params.

Comment: @popcorn Yes, but if you add the script I posted to your template and submit your form it will do just that. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: oh yeah but when I submit the form the #tokenfields no longer have the values, it's only in the context and in the GET

Comment: @popcorn You mean after returning from your defense_planning view to the form the tokenfields are empty? Why are you not just putting them back there?

Comment: I don't know, should I just put them back?

Comment: It ain't that easy, Because I'm using bootstrap token fields so it generates the tokens automatically. And I have different label and value so I can show like label= "New York" and value = 4 etc..

Comment: I would need something like <button name="remove" value="{{c.id}}" onclick="location.href='{% url 'handleget' %}'"></button>

and in 
def handleget: 
   countries = request.GET('countries')
   countries = countries.remove('remove')
   return new_GET
.
.

Comment: @popcorn I understand you are looking for something different than this solution. I posted an alternative answer